# How to place a logo using HTML & JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to put the logo first and to the right of the gradient code. This code is used in a Microstrategy(business Intelligence tool) landing page. We used simpler code earlier. I need help in making the 2nd code block work same as first one.

```html
<DIV id=grad1>
  <TABLE width="100%">
    <TBODY>
      <TR>
        <TD style="BACKGROUND: white" width="30%" align=left>
          <IMG src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/d/d8/Url-logo.png" width=245 height=50>
        </TD>
        <TD style="FONT-SIZE: 40px; FONT-FAMILY: Helvetica, sans-serif; BACKGROUND:         none transparent scroll repeat 0% 0%; COLOR: white; PADDING-BOTTOM: 5px; TEXT-    ALIGN: left; PADDING-TOP: 5px; PADDING-LEFT: 20px; BACKGROUND: linear-    gradient(to right, #7AC143 , #3DA040, #007A3C)"
        ; width="70%">Enterprise Reporting
        </TD>
      </TR>
    </TBODY>
  </TABLE>
  <BR>
</DIV>



<DIV id=grad1>
  <TABLE width="100%">
    <TBODY>
      <TR>
        <TD style="BACKGROUND: white" width="30%" align=left>
          <IMG src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/d/d8/Url-logo.png" width=245 height=230>
        </TD>
        <CANVAS id=myCanvas style="BORDER-TOP: #d3d3d3 1px solid;     BORDER-RIGHT: #d3d3d3 1px solid; BORDER-BOTTOM: #d3d3d3 1px solid; BORDER-LEFT:     #d3d3d3 1px solid" height="115" width="900">Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
          <SCRIPT>
            var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
            var c1 = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var ctx1 = c.getContext("2d");
            var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 900, 0);
            gradient.addColorStop(0, "#7AC143");
            gradient.addColorStop(0.5, "#3DA040");
            gradient.addColorStop(1, "#007A3C");
            ctx.textAlign = 'left';
            ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
            ctx.fillRect(0, 20, 900, 75);
            ctx1.fillStyle = "white";
            ctx1.font = "40px Helvetica, sans-serif";
            ctx1.fillText("Enterprise Reporting", 450, 65);

          </SCRIPT>
        </CANVAS>
      </TR>
    </TBODY>
  </TABLE>
</DIV>
```

Comment: This may not be feasible since this is pre-existing code but if you can avoid using tables for layout, that will also help.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest thing is that your canvas isn't inside the table. You need to include it in a new table cell (`<TD></TD>`).

```
<TD style="BACKGROUND: white" width="30%" align=left>
  <IMG src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/d/d8/Url-logo.png" width=245 height=230>
</TD>
<TD>
  <CANVAS id=myCanvas style="BORDER-TOP: #d3d3d3 1px solid;     BORDER-RIGHT: #d3d3d3 1px solid; BORDER-BOTTOM: #d3d3d3 1px solid; BORDER-LEFT:     #d3d3d3 1px solid" height="115" width="900">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
  </CANVAS>
</TD>
```

Additionally, it's generally bad practice to insert script tags in the middle of your html. I would include the script above the canvas.

Finally, you mentioned you're new to HTML (maybe coding generally?). It's much easier to read code that has been properly formatted.

Long lines of code that includes multiple different types of actions are incredibly hard to parse and understand (not to mention read without scrolling).

```
<TD style="BACKGROUND: white" width="30%" align=left><IMG     src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/d/d8/Url-logo.png" width=245     height=230></TD><CANVAS id=myCanvas style="BORDER-TOP: #d3d3d3 1px solid;     BORDER-RIGHT: #d3d3d3 1px solid; BORDER-BOTTOM: #d3d3d3 1px solid; BORDER-LEFT:     #d3d3d3 1px solid" height="115" width="900">Your browser does not support the     HTML5 canvas tag.
```

As opposed to more orderly code like my response. The TDs are broken out. The material contained in them are indented so you can easily tell what information belongs inside which TDs (I would do the same with the DIV, TABLE, TRs, etc).

Comment: Thanks Chris G. After including canvas inside a table, it started working. But when i try to put Script above canvas my gradient didnt show. so i reverted by keeping canvas on top of script.